# Schedule Parse Background Job Programmatically

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Can you create and schedule a Parse Background Job in code. I want to automatically send an email 30mins after a user sign up?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can have a job which runs at a set period and queries to see what work needs to be done. This could be searching for new users, or it could be looking at a new class of work items (which are deleted after the task is complete).